# Is there a way to detect mouse wheel hardware with web programming?

Tags: javascript, flash, hardware, mousewheel

I have a website, and I want to highly encourage my users to use a mouse with a mousewheel when navigating my website.

But, if they already have a mousewheel, such encouragement would be redundant. They wouldn't need encouragement simply because they already have the hardware that facilitates the website.

Is there a way to check if they have a mouse with a mousewheel? Perhaps with flash, javascript, or some other language?

---

Comment: Please be aware, I'm not trying to find the mouse wheel event. There are mouses without mousewheels. If a user goes to my website with one of these mouses, I want to encourage them to come back with a better equipped mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no access to hardware information like that for mainly security reasons (fingerprinting) as well as to avoid overhead from probing code needed for each platform etc. which is generally not so useful.

The only thing we can do, like with for example touch events, is to subscribe to the `mousewheel` event and establish it exist if ever triggered. I think it's a fair assumption to make that most people having a mouse-wheel tend to use it, so the event will trigger sooner or later. You can also request, if possible in your scenario, the user to use the mouse wheel or click a skip button to pass a small dialog for example. If button was clicked assume the user does not have a mouse-wheel.

It's the closest we get in any case...

Comment: That's a great idea, thank you very much! A preliminary test to prove they have a mouse-wheel!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article that describes **How to Use the Mouse Wheel Event**, and gives an example: http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/

Try This using `addEventListener`. Below is a simple example to detect mousewheel scroll up and down

```js
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e){
    wDelta = e.wheelDelta < 0 ? 'down' : 'up';
    console.log(wDelta);
});
```

Comment: Hello, first off, thank you for the answer, but I'm not trying to find the mouse wheel event in javascript. I'm trying to detect if they actually have a mouse wheel, like the physical thing. I'm sorry if it sounds confusing!